# PHP-OCI connection

Tags: php, oracle

I am new to PHP and am trying to connect to a oracle database on some server.

However the php script is not executing properly.

```
 <?php
 echo "started \n";
 // Create connection to Oracle
 $conn = oci_connect("username", "password", "abc.def.ghi.com");
 if (!$conn) {
    $m = oci_error();
    echo $m['message'], "\n";
    exit;
 }
 else {
    print "Connected to Oracle!";
 }
 // Close the Oracle connection
 oci_close($conn);
 ?>
```

It prints started, but after that it does not print any error or "Connected to Oracle".

php -l filename.php gives "no syntax errors".

Comment: Is the OCI8 php Extension installed on your server? You can find out with the following command: php -i | grep -i oci8

Comment: Unfortunately for now I am using windows. So the above wont work.

Comment: You can also create a php file with <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it. Browse to that page and look for anything oci8 :)

Comment: No. I cannot find anything.

Comment: Also when install oci, I was asked (in tutorials) to remove semicolon from the line "extension=php_oci8_11g.dll", but I cannot find that line in php.ini

Comment: You'd better put then there and point it to the your PHP-OCI dll file. Furthermore a `display_errors=On`in php.ini will help you a bit more on a development system to track down errors.

Answer (score 0):

Was PHP compiled with oracle support? Check your error log, if not you'll error out on oci_connect() and not reach anything else.

(display errors would also be of help)

Comment: Yeah! oci_connect() is giving error. The function is not found.